# “`/bin/sh: apxs: command not found`” when installing `mod_wsgi`

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I got the crazy error message 
"`/bin/sh: apxs: command not found`" when installing `mod_wsgi`.

I researched some ways which I may install the `httpd-devel` with 
 "`yum install httpd-devel`"

Actually, I got the message "`Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)`" with "`httpd -V`"

And the version is **python2.7 mod_wsgi-4.5.15**.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `yum provides apxs` should tell you what package you need

Comment: You should try checking for help/answer on unix.stackexchange.com.

As you eluded to, `/usr/bin/apxs` is provided by `httpd-devel` on a RHEL7/CentOS7 system.  However, I'm not sure what OS you're using, since the `httpd -V` output shows "Unix" as the OS, and you seem to be using `/bin/sh` as (default?) shell; which doesn't align with the newest versions of RHEL/CentOS at least.

Comment: `yum provides /*bin/apxs` might work better; though, that shouldn't be the problem here, AFAICT.

Comment: thanks all！I finally find the way to point the apxs‘ position     
like "./configure –with-apxs=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs"